# An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info"

Tags: eclipse

Since a week, in my project occours an error, when I want to change the class name to file name by eclipse.

Example: file name is "RolePermission.java"; class name is "Example"

```
...
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class Example {
  
} // EoC
```

Eclipse makes a red circle with white cross no the left side in the editor. Clicking to it, eclipse gives hints to solve the error, that the file name and class name are different.
When I tried to "Rename type to 'RolePermission' I get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/dom/LinkedNodeFinder.findByNode(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Name;)[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Name; @11: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type '[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Name;' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to '[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/SimpleName;'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @11
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode', 'org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Name', '[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Name;' }
    stack: { '[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Name;' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b b801 044d 2cc6 0008 2cb8 016b b02b
    0000010: b601 06b6 00f6 3e1d 101e 9f00 0f1d 100a
    0000020: 9f00 091d 1012 a000 32bb 00d0 59b7 00d2
    0000030: 3a04 bb01 0959 2b19 04b7 010b 3a05 2a19
    0000040: 05b6 00d8 1904 1904 b600 dcbd 0107 b600
    0000050: dfc0 010e b801 6bb0 04bd 0107 5903 2b53
    0000060: b801 6bb0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@15,Object[#270])
    append_frame(@41,Integer)
    same_frame(@88)
```

Is there a way to solve the problem?